# PHP str replace sizes

Tags: php, str-replace

I have this code and want to use str_replace to remove | that comes after each size

Old code:

`<?= ($line ["sizes"])."\n"; ?>`

New code:

`<?=  $line = "One size"; $sizes = str_replace("|", "", $line); print $line; "\n"; ?>`

But it doesnt show the sizes like Small Medium Large, as in the old code.

Thanx.

Comment: Could you please edit your post to add some code?

Comment: What is the "new code"? and possible what is `loc();`

Comment: according to your question `$new_code=''` will solve it. pls update. what is the new code ?

Comment: ? $line ["sizes"]:loc("One size") is for english language, so I can tranlate it to another language, I remove it now so it doest confused people.

Comment: much better ! thanks. now we need to know who is loc

Comment: The new code is how I tried to remove the | that automaticly is added to every size, it doest look nice so I want to try to remove with str_replace

Comment: do you have any output example from the old code ?

Comment: Old code look like this https://billedeupload.dk/?v=bTuZa.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your question, but if I only see the sentence

> I have this code and want to use str_replace to remove | that comes after each size

you should make use of `explode` and `implode` instead of `str_replace` better:

```
$sizeStr = "1|2|3";
$sizes = explode("|", $sizeStr); // Array("1", "2", "3");
echo implode("\\n", $sizes);
```

This will show

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: Sorry its not exactly what I meant, Don't Panic gave me the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your new code, I get the following output:

> One sizeOne size

I assume with your new code that is probably what you're getting as well. Here is what's happening there:

```
$line = "One size";
//1. Sets $line equal to "One size" (and prints it because of the short tag.)

$sizes = str_replace("|", "", $line);
//2. Replaces '|' with '' in the string "One size" (it isn't there.)

print $line;
//3. Prints "One size" again.
```

If your old code was pretty much doing what you wanted it to (other than printing the extra bar), probably all you need to do to it is add str_replace like this.

```
<?= (str_replace('|', '', $line["sizes"]))."\n"; ?>
```

Comment: Thanx that was what I exactly wanted, now it looks more clean.

Comment: I have one more question now the small sizes like S M lies next to each other and not as a list, how can I make them as a list? Thanx

Comment: @tech77 Sorry I didn't respond to your comment; I was asleep. I assume we're in different time zones.